# Getting error while authenticating salesforce login

Tags: c#, salesforce

I'm using soap api for salesforce login authentication in C# but getting below error.

> UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization.
>   Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using
>   https.

So I've already deactivated "Critical Updates" in salesforce but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you please share the code which is throwing this error? Please also point out which line of code is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce.com currently allows the disabling of TLSv1, a security protocol used by web services to talk to each other. If this version of TLS is disabled in your Salesforce service, Soapbox Engage will not be able to function properly in some cases, since some of the Soapbox Engage servers still require the use of TLSv1

**Here is the solution:**

you need to set the below security protocol in your project before calling the login service mehod of salesforce

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
Logging.Log("Login to Salesforce Started", Logging.LogItemType.Info);

var sfBinding = new SforceService();
var result = sfBinding.login("SfUsername", "SfPassword", Environment.MachineName) + "SfToken");
```